# Run terminal from script and substitute command with a variable

Tags: bash, variables, terminal

Can anyone tell me how can this be accomplished ?

```
COMMAND=TEST 
xterm -hold -e 'echo $COMMAND'
```

Using this example, I expect "TEST", but I get nothing.

Comment: Warning: storing commands in variables is problematic. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

It pops the xterm window with the output of `TEST`

```
variable="TEST"
COMMAND="echo $variable"
xterm -hold -e $COMMAND
```

In your code variable is not expanded due to single quotes:

```
'echo $COMMAND'
```